# apache camel cxf soap

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, esb

I am developing a web service (soap) using apache camel cxf I encountered this error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Part
>   {http://blueprint.camel.ngt.tn/}return should be of type
>   [Ltn.ngt.camel.blueprint.WB_subscriptions;, not
>   tn.ngt.camel.blueprint.WB_subscriptions   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.checkPart(DataWriterImpl.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handleAsync(Server.java:410)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:519)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

is there anyone who can help me solve this problem, 
here is my source code

**blueprint**

```
 <cxf:cxfEndpoint  address="http://localhost:9191/cxf/Subsriptions" id="claimEndpoint" serviceClass="tn.ngt.camel.blueprint.WbSubscriptionService"/>

 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
<route id="GetWb_Subscription">
     <from uri="cxf:bean:claimEndpoint"/>
   <!--  <from uri="timer:foo?period=10000"/>-->
    <to uri="sql:select * from WB_SUBSCRIPTIONS?dataSource=dataSource"/>
    <to uri="bean:tn.ngt.camel.blueprint.Transformer?method=ToList(Exchange)"/>  
     <to uri="bean:tn.ngt.camel.blueprint.Transformer?method=getSubscriptions"/>
  <log message="The message contains ${body}"/>
</route>
```

**WbSubscriptionService**

```
    public interface WbSubscriptionService {
    public List<WB_subscriptions> getSubscriptions();

}
```

**Transformer**

```
public class Transformer {
public static List<WB_subscriptions> subscription= new ArrayList<WB_subscriptions>();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<WB_subscriptions> ToList(Exchange exchange) throws NumberFormatException, ParseException{
    List<?> messages= exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
    List<WB_subscriptions>LstWb_Sub= new ArrayList<WB_subscriptions>();
    for(int i=0;i<messages.size();i++){
        Map<String,Object> row = (Map<String,Object>) messages.get(i);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
        WB_subscriptions wb= new WB_subscriptions( Integer.parseInt(row.get("CUST_ACCOUNT").toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(row.get("PACKAGE_ID").toString()),Integer.parseInt(row.get("CUST_MOBILE").toString()) , formatter.parse(row.get("DATE_CREATION").toString()));
                System.out.println(wb.getCust_mobile());
                LstWb_Sub.add(wb);  

    }
    subscription=LstWb_Sub;
    System.out.println("List 1 "+subscription);
    return LstWb_Sub;

}
public List<WB_subscriptions> getSubscriptions() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("bonjour "+subscription);
    return subscription;
}
```

thanks in advance: D

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message simply says that the return type must be **a collection of** `WB_subscriptions` not a single `WB_subscriptions`.

You can read the first part of the error message as follows:

- `[` => Array of ...
- `L...;` => between `L` and `;` is a fully classified class name
- `tn.ngt.camel.blueprint.WB_subscriptions` => your class name

However, there are some issues when returning a Java collection from the webservice (for example [this one](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/223)).

Therefore try to either return an Array of `WB_subscriptions` or wrap the `List` in a Bean and return the single Bean that contains the list.

Comment: yes ,but I am returning a WB-subscriptions type list, I did not find the source of the error

Comment: Where is this stacktrace thrown? On the server or on the client that calls the service?

Comment: when I try to consume the service with soap Ui

Comment: Have you tried to return an array of objects instead of a Java-List?

Comment: And have you tried to return a single object that wraps the list?

Comment: yes i tried ,  it works when i change the return type (list of wb-subscruptions-> object wb-Subscriptions) buti don't know why this error appears when i return list

Comment: Most probably a bug or an incompatibility in a framework. For example https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/223